# Se repiten los datos en los inputs select ¿Cómo evito esto?

Tags: php

tengo 3 `inputs select` que contienen fechas lo que quiero lograr es evitar que se repitan los valores que forman estos elementos:
Esta es la fecha con la que la trabajo **2016-12-31** Esta se obtiene de una base de datos y es un registro
**Lo que muestra**
Dia = 31-01-02-03.
Mes = Diciembre-Enero-Enero.
Año = 2016-2017-2017.
**Lo que quiero mostrar**
Dia = 31-01-02-03.
Mes = Diciembre-Enero.
Año = 2016-2017.
**Lo que he intentado**

```
if ($echo==1) {         
    if (2016==$anio) {
        $ANIO .='<option value="'.$anio.'" selected="selected">'.$anio.'</option>';
    }else{
        $ANIO .='<option value="'.$anio.'">'.$anio.'</option>';
    }           
}   
if(2016==$anio){
    $echo=0;
}else{
    $echo=1;
}
```

Esto funciona si el ciclo es de 3 pero al ser superior repite los datos. 


**El codigo**

```
<?php
    function nombreme($mes){
     setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish');  
     $nombre=strftime("%B",mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, 1, 2000)); 
     return $nombre;
    }
        $DIA = '<select name="DIA" class="Formularios" id="DIA">';
        $MES = '<select name="MES" class="Formularios" id="MES" style="width:80px">';
        $ANIO = '<select name="ANIO" class="Formularios" id="ANIO">';
        $echo=1;
        $echoMes=1;
        for ($i=0; $i <4 ; $i++) { 
            $fecha = "2016-12-31";//fecha obtenida de la base de datos
            $nuevafecha = strtotime ( '+'.$i.' day' , strtotime ( $fecha ) ) ;//suma de dias a la fecha
            $nuevafecha = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $nuevafecha );
            $separa= explode("-", $nuevafecha);
            $dia=$separa[2];
            $mes=$separa[1];
            $anio=$separa[0];

            if(strlen($dia)==1){
                $dia="0".$dia;
            }
            if(strlen($mes)==1){
                $mes="0".$mes;
            }
            //creacion de los select de la fecha dinamicamente
            if (31==$dia) {     
                $DIA .='<option value="'.$dia.'" selected="selected">'.$dia.'</option>';        
            } else { 
                $DIA .='<option value="'.$dia.'">'.$dia.'</option>';
            }
            if ($echoMes==1) {
                if (02==$mes) {
                    $MES .='<option value="'.$mes.'" selected="selected">'.nombreme($mes).'</option>';      
                }else{
                    $MES .='<option value="'.$mes.'">'.nombremes($mes).'</option>';
                }
            }
            if(12==$mes){
                $echoMes=0;
            }else{
                $echoMes=1;
            }
            if ($echo==1) {         

                if (2016==$anio) {
                    $ANIO .='<option value="'.$anio.'" selected="selected">'.$anio.'</option>';
                }else{
                    $ANIO .='<option value="'.$anio.'">'.$anio.'</option>';
                }           
            }   
            if(2016==$anio){
                $echo=0;
            }else{
                $echo=1;
            }
        }
        $DIA.='</select>';
        $MES.='</select>';
        $ANIO.='</select>';
        echo $DIA;
        echo $MES;
        echo $ANIO;
?>
```

Comment: ¿De dónde vienen los datos, de un array? Si es así, ¿por qué no controlas la creación de array para que no repita datos? Si no puedes controlar la creación del array, puedes hacer que elimine los datos repetidos.

Comment: La fecha la obtengo de base de datos y solo es un registro, dada una fecha hay un rango de 4 días los cuales los creo en el código con el ciclo `for`

Comment: Pero ¿esa `fecha` que obtienes de la base de datos es la que contiene el rango de 4 días? ¿Puedes mostrar la forma en que obtienes el rango de 4 días, si es un array, una cadena, o qué es? Creo que puedes limpiar esa variable, quitando los años que se repiten.

Comment: A la fecha le sumo 4 días en en el ciclo `for` es la fecha de creación de un lote con la cual se puede trabajar hasta cuatro dias desde que fue crado

Comment: ahhh ya entendi tu problema.. mes y año no pueden estar en el mismo for que la fecha!! pq si no sumas 4 a las fechas.. pero a los otros dos tambien!

Comment: Claro @gbianchi trataba de hacerlo en el mismo ciclo condicionando con `if` pero parece que es un poco implosible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solución**
La solución fue mas simple de lo pensado, gracias a los comentarios aportados.
Dejo el código por si alguien tiene un problema parecido:

```
    <?php
    function nombremes($_mes){
        setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish');  
        $nombre=strftime("%B",mktime(0, 0, 0, $_mes, 1, 2000)); 
        return $nombre;
    }
    //funciones para obtener dias mes o meses y años o año;
    function _dia($_dia,$_seleccionado){
        $DIA = '<select name="DIA" class="Formularios" id="DIA">';
        foreach ($_dia as $dia) {
            if ($_seleccionado==$dia) {     
                $DIA .='<option value="'.$dia.'" selected="selected">'.$dia.'</option>';        
            } else { 
                $DIA .='<option value="'.$dia.'">'.$dia.'</option>';
            }
        }
        $DIA.='</select>';
        return $DIA;
    }
    function _mes($_mes,$_seleccionado){
        $MES = '<select name="MES" class="Formularios" id="MES" style="width:80px">';
        foreach (array_unique($_mes)as $mes) {
            if ($_seleccionado==$mes) {
                $MES .='<option value="'.$mes.'" selected="selected">'.nombremes($mes).'</option>';     
            }else{
                $MES .='<option value="'.$mes.'">'.nombremes($mes).'</option>';
            }
        }
        $MES.='</select>';
        return $MES;
    }
    function _anio($_anio,$_seleccionado){
        $ANIO = '<select name="ANIO" class="Formularios" id="ANIO">';
        foreach (array_unique($_anio) as $anio) {
            if ($_seleccionado==$anio) {
                $ANIO .='<option value="'.$anio.'" selected="selected">'.$anio.'</option>';
            }else{
                $ANIO .='<option value="'.$anio.'">'.$anio.'</option>';
            }
        }
        $ANIO.='</select>';
        return $ANIO;
    }

    for ($i=0; $i <4 ; $i++) { //ciclo para sumar días
//fecha a la cual se sumaran los días dependiendo del ciclo
        $fecha = "2016-12-31";
        $nuevafecha = strtotime ( '+'.$i.' day' , strtotime ( $fecha ) ) ;
        $nuevafecha = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $nuevafecha );
        $separa= explode("-", $nuevafecha);
    //separo la fecha obtenida de la suma
        $dia=$separa[2];
        $mes=$separa[1];
        $anio=$separa[0];
    //almaceno los datos obtenido al separar la fecha en array
        $arrayDia[] = $dia;
        $arrayMes[] = $mes;
        $arrayAnio[] = $anio;           
    }
    echo _dia($arrayDia, 31)." "._mes($arrayMes, 12)." "._anio($arrayAnio, 2016);
    ?>
```